# Default destructor when using pointer to base class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, default, destructor

```
class A
{
    int a;
};

class B : public A
{
    int b;
};

int main(void)
{
    A * p = new B;
    delete p;   // (1)
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code both classes have default compiler-generated destructors. Both classes also have only Plain Old Data as members so I don't need manually written d'tors which would free any resources. So my question is - after the call in `(1)` will the default destructor free the entirety of `B`'s instance or will there be any memory leaks? I know that I could use a virtual destructor here but I'm not sure how default d'tors behave.

Comment: If you delete through pointer to base class, you need virtual destructor.

Comment: There is no polymorphism here.

Comment: My understanding was that this is only undefined behaviour if there were virtual methods involved?

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do invokes undefined behavior, so declaring A destructor as `virtual` can be considered mandatory.

```
delete p
```

Will try to delete `p` as an instance of `A` but since the destructor is not declared virtual the correct runtime implementation is not called.

Mind that this doesn't happen when you don't have a pointer but just a concrete object, eg

```
A a = B();
```

Because object slicing occurs before, so when `a` exits the scope it's just an `A`

Comment: If you destroy a type through a pointer to its parent without casting to the exact type you're destroying, the destructor is required to be virtual. It will probably "happen to work" when only POD is involved, but it's definitely not a good idea.

Comment: Then what should I do? Create an **empty** virtual destructor (which does absolutely nothing besides being virtual)?

Comment: @Nps `virtual ~A() = default` should be fine.

Comment: @NPS That is what you should do.

Comment: @NPS You can imagine that the C++ language might have basically made all destructors virtual, just to avoid the possibility of getting this wrong. But that would violate the principle of "you only pay for what you use".

Comment: @remyabel That's only in `C++11`, right? In `C++98/03` the only way is to **define** the virtual d'tor myself?

Comment: @David Schwartz - and would completely eliminate the possibility of implementing classes/structs as POD